# Identify this part?

Tags: wood, woodworking

Can someone identify this part? It's from the page of Home Depot.

It looks like a heavy-duty bracket.

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a "tension tie" used both to tie joists to the house through the ledger, and to mount posts on the outside of the rim joists. There are different versions of these but most tie to an inside joist with nails or screws, then to the post (or bracket inside the wall) with a bolt.

Example Simpson version:

[image]

And here's one installed, seen from the face of the tie:

[image]

Comment: +1 for including clarifying pics. So what is the benefit compared to carriage bolt (as also seen in the pic) plus separate hanger?

Comment: Benefits: code compliance (ymmv), and the joist is a better thing to pull on (versus the rim board) with the kind of rotational force a post exerts. Note the varieties that Simpson sells have different size holes for the through bolt. The post application is probably a DTT-2Z.